# I am using Vue and DotNet with SPATemplates 2.02 using WebPack etc

Tags: .net, vue.js

When I change any code the changes are not reflected in the browser even if I restart the App in VSCode or Browser.

```
module.exports = (env) => {
const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

return [{
    stats: { modules: false },
    context: __dirname,
    resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
    entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.ts' },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.vue\.html$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'vue-loader', options: { loaders: { js: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' } } },
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CheckerPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(isDevBuild ? 'development' : 'production')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
        // Plugins that apply in development builds only
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
            moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
        })
    ] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
    ])
}];
```

};

Comment: You can take a look at this template. https://github.com/danijelh/aspnetcore-vue-typescript-template After running it will watch for changes, you can just hit F5 and focus on frontend development without stopping the application or running the command again.

Answer (score 0):

That's the normal behavior. In order to apply the changes you should re-bundle/regenerate the bundle.js file in the dist folder to see the changes, then to refresh the browser. you can do that by running. `webpack webpack.config.js`